# Is PSTricks breaking LaTeX?

Tags: pstricks, bugs

Sorry for the newspaper headline title :P

I have a document in which I (ab)use LaTeX's control structures, namely `\@for`. Naturally, the contents of some of these loops contain `\par` agraph breaks.

I added `\usepackage{pstricks}` to my document and I got tons of `Runaway argument`s. `\tracingall` here and there, and I reduced the problem to this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@for\el:=a,b,c\do{%
A long text with \el\par or not so long after all\dots\par}

\end{document}
```

Once you uncomment `\usepackage{pstricks}` TeX throws an error saying that `Paragraph ended before \@fornoop was complete.`

On line 90 of `pstricks.tex` one finds:

```
% stolen from latex.ltx to make it TeX compatible
     \def\@fornoop#1\@@#2#3{}
```

while the LaTeX kernel has:

```
\long\def\@fornoop#1\@@#2#3{}
```

---

Why does PSTricks doesn't define `\@fornoop` as `\long`? Is this intended or a bug? If it is intended, then why?

Comment: Which compiler do you use with `pstricks`?

Comment: @Bernard I was compiling with pdfLaTeX. To be honest I didn't try other compilers as I thought it would be irrelevant because this doesn't seem to be a compiler dependent issue.

Comment: Witpdflatex, did you think of loading `auto-pst-pdf` (*after* pstricks) and enabling `-shell-escape`? Without it, you can compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: @Bernard Actually, the problem arised when I loaded both `psvectorian` (which loads `pstricks`) then`auto-pst-pdf`, so no that doesn't help, neither does `xelatex` (I tried just now). Solving the problem is quite easy, just copy the LaTeX definition of `\@fornoop` after `pstricks`, or load Nicola Talbot's `xfor`. My question was more if this is an expected behavior. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: should be fixed with next update ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the documented sources of LaTeX you will see that making that `\long` is a "recent" change and pstricks would have copied an older version and not yet caught up

```
% \changes{v1.0g}{1995/08/16}{Made defs long}
% \changes{v1.0h}{2007/08/06}{Really make defs long}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\@fornoop#1\@@#2#3{}
```

Comment: Loading [`xfor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xfor) after `pstricks` might help. `xfor` was written before that change and one of the reasons for writing it was to patch `\@for` to make it long.

Comment: Hmm... Makes sense. Should I report this to the maintainer of PSTricks? (It's [Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478/herbert), right?)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot `xfor` not only solves *this* issue, but it solves far too many problems I had before with loops. Thanks for the tip :)